# How can I make the launcher disappear after notification

Tags: unity

I have a generally stock configured Unity 2d, with the launcher in auto-hide mode.
When I get a notification, the launcher pops out and the relevant icon wiggles.  That is all functioning well.

My problem is that the launcher pops out for maybe 5 seconds before hiding.  Often times I'm typing or using the mouse on the portion of the display that is now covered by the launcher.  After I've mentally received the notification is there some way to tell the launcher "I've seen this, you can go away now".

Note, I'm not wanting to modify or shorten the default display time. I'd be very happy to hit 'alt-h' or some other key combination to make it go away.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the whole launcher pops out even though the design is to only pop out the relevant icon (as it is implemented in Unity 3d). It is technically feasible but nobody has had time to do it.

Otherwise I guess we could as a temporary measure shorten the time: 5 seconds is a bit high.